# Embed HTML tag in Flask WTForms field

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask with Jinja2/WTForms to build a login page and I want to customize a "Remember Me" checkbox. To do this, I would like to embed an empty `<span>` tag into the form's label field. Here is the Jinja2 code in the HTML file:

```
{{ login_user_form.remember|safe }} {{ login_user_form.remember.label }}
```

which generates the following HTML:

```
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" value="y"> <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
```

However, the following HTML is what I would ultimately like it to be  - notice the `<span>` tag embedded within the label.

```
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" value="y"> <label for="remember"><span></span>Remember Me</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the *span* tag in your label name and use the *safe* filter.

```
remember = YourField(name='<span></span>Remember Me')
```

And then

```
{{ login_user_form.remember|safe }} {{ login_user_form.remember.label|safe }}
```